# Is there another better way to get file ext from a given path in python

Tags: python

I'm new in python, As we know, we can get file ext from a path by use:

```
os.path.splitext(path)[1][1:]
```

This works well, but seems not quite beautiful, I want to ask: is there another better way to get the file ext

Comment: Not in the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The readable way would be

```
name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
ext = ext[1:]
```

though that's no longer a single expression. If you want a single expression, wrap this in a function:

```
def extension(path):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
    return ext[1:]
```

Be aware that on some systems, files *may* have an empty extension, e.g.

```
>>> os.path.splitext('ham.')
('ham', '.')
```

and you're treating those the same as files with no extension at all (just `ham`). Usually, that difference doesn't matter, but in some cases it might, which is why `splitext` works the way it does.

Comment: +1 I guess, I wouldn't do this myself however edit: actually I probably would